# SSRS Subscriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to refresh data every week and run subscriptions weekly.
My question is,

If email has sent to person already ( record in dataset) and the same person appears to be in the dataset next week, i would like to not send the subscription for him and would like to send email for the new persons only.

Example,

Let's say :

There are three records returned last week when run the query:

```
Employee Id Employee    Date
1001    Saifa   07-08-2018
1002    Oliver  06-08-2018
1003    Varun   07-08-2018
```

And this week the query returns 2 records :

```
Employee Id Employee    Date
1001    Saifa   13-08-2018
1005    Natasha 13-08-2018
```

The email should only be sent to Natasha, how can this be possible?
Please help.

Thanks!
Sindhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude employees who have a record from a previous date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    AND EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID 
                            FROM T 
                            WHERE DATE < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

The NOT IN will check for previous dates for the Employee.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by employeeid) as mindate
      from t
     ) t
where mindate = '2018-08-13'
```

Comment: The above example are two different datasets retrieved at two different times , as written

Comment: What is the "business" logic that dictates that Saifa is excluded in week 2?